# Is there a way to see a list of stopped VM instances in IBM Cloud?

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

To clean up, I want to see what VM instances have been stopped but not terminated. I don't think there is any policy that will terminate them automatically, and I cannot find a way to see how long the instances have been stopped. I am just working from documentation, though, so anyone with practical experience might be able to offer some advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a CLI command, IBM Cloud CLI has an `infrastructure-service` plugin to help you see the instance information. The instructions to set up the plugin can be found in this [solution tutorial](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-getting-started)

```
ibmcloud is instances
```

You can use `grep` with the command to see the instances that are stopped

```
ibmcloud is instances | grep `stopped`
```

To get the ID of the stopped VM, run the following command

```
ibmcloud is instances | grep 'stopped' | awk '{print $1}'
```